# Using 'unfold' of a Fixpoint inside the recursive step of the induction

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to prove something in coq and the same problem keeps coming up;
I want to unfold the definition of a Fixpoint inside the recursive (not nil) step of induction. Unfold works as expected, here's an example:

Before unfolding the list reverse (rev) definition:

```
  n : nat
  l' : natlist
  IHl' : rev (rev l') = l'
  ============================
  rev (rev (n :: l')) = n :: l'
```

After:

```
  n : nat
  l' : natlist
  IHl' : rev (rev l') = l'
  ============================
  (fix rev (l : natlist) : natlist := match l with
                                      | [ ] => [ ]
                                      | h :: t => rev t ++ [h]
                                      end)
    ((fix rev (l : natlist) : natlist := match l with
                                         | [ ] => [ ]
                                         | h :: t => rev t ++ [h]
                                         end) l' ++ [n]) = n :: l'
```

So far so good. Now I would expect `simpl` to figure out I'm on the non-nil case of the induction since `n :: l'` can never be nil, 
and simplify away the nil case of the match (`[ ] => [ ]`), keeping only the non-nil part of the definition.

Unfortunately it does not do that implicitly. How can I make `unfold` of a recursive Fixpoint definition play well with induction? How do I get:

```
  n : nat
  l' : natlist
  IHl' : rev (rev l') = l'
  ============================
  rev (rev l' ++ [n]) = n :: l'
```

According to the `rev` definition for the inner `rev`.

Note: The use of Lists is irrelevant here, the same technique can be used for any inductively defined types.

**Edit:** Definition of rev and proof that leads to the *After* state.

```
Fixpoint rev (l:natlist) : natlist :=
  match l with
  | nil    => nil
  | h :: t => rev t ++ [h]
  end.

Theorem rev_involutive : forall l : natlist,
  rev (rev l) = l.
Proof.
  intros l. induction l as [| n l'].
  - reflexivity.
  - unfold rev.
```

Comment: Please try to submit a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's a lot easier to answer when we can step through the proof an try different things.

Comment: Added the definition of `rev` and the proof that leads to the After state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `After:` is basically `rev (rev l' ++ [n])` (with `rev` unfolded) which means that the reduction you want to see happening has already happened. Now you probably want to prove an auxiliary lemma akin to `rev (xs ++ ys) = rev ys ++ rev xs`.

Comment: Sure, and I have that proven already, but this proof is used as an example. What I really want is to reduce the pesky `match` that got unfolded from the `rev` definition, given the nil case of the pattern match is impossible. What if I prove `Forall n: nat, l: natlist, n :: l ~= [ ]` but that should be obvious from the definition of `cons`.

Comment: As I've said: It's already been simplified. If you try `fold rev`, you'll see that it has now been reduced to `rev (rev l' ++ [n])`.

Comment: Yes! Fold is what I wanted! It's super counter-intuitive btw that the key to the proof is `unfold rev. fold rev. `, reading it seems like it does nothing.  Like why wouldn't that be one of the first strategies that `simpl` tries by default?

Comment: `simpl` instead `unfold rev; fold rev` does work for on my machine.

Comment: I dug a bit deeper and it seems there's a good reason for which Coq doesn't allow evaluation of a recursive match definition, even when the input will clearly match the non-nil branch. In my example, `n :: l'`  can never be `nil` but if Coq where to evaluate the match and get rid of the `nil` branch, there would be no exit condition for the recursion, leading to possibly infinite loops.